# UIAutomation failed to load plugin

Tags: ios, instruments, ui-automation, xcode-instruments, xcrun

I have a project set up such that one of target launches UIAutomation when build process finishes. Instruments is launched from Python script which eventually call the usual "xcrun instruments ..." command on bash.

It worked for quite a while without a problem. After upgrading Xcode to 4.4, I'm starting to see "Failed to Load XXX Locator Plugin." error message. Any Ideas where to start track down problem?

Any clue would be helpful! Thanks in advance.

[image: Output from Instruments]

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923272/running-uiautomation-scripts-from-xcode/14051438#14051438 - it's starting to look like this is an honest-to-goodness bug in Xcode.

Comment: I had the same issue recently. I think I finally found a solution. Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14161519/343340